# Url format affects performance/caching?

Tags: html, performance, caching

In terms of performance (load times or caching implications) is there a difference between:

```
<img src='http://www.example.com/img/logo.png'> <!-- Absolute path + Domain -->
<img src='/img/logo.png'>                       <!-- Absolute path -->
<img src='../logo.png'>                         <!-- Relative path -->
```

I vaguely recall that the first one is viewed as an external link and not cached by the browser?

Comment: To load any of your examples the browser has to resolve every path. So in the end they are all valid URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as @Nick says in the comment. A HTTP request will always contain a full path. Whether the source path is relative or absolute is completely meaningless for performance.